# How to store and retrieve data efficiently in main memory?

Tags: java, spring-boot, memory, cpu-usage

I have the following problem:

I have a spring boot service that has to handle a lot of traffic (around 5.000 incoming POST requests per second on several TCP connections in parallel).

The incoming data contains some basic sales data. It is used to create a dashboard which is updated via a GET every second and displays only the past minute. Data has not to be stored persistent, but can be thrown away, even losing some data after a restart is not a problem.

Main concerns are memory and cpu usage: I want to use as few memory and cpu as possible.

My idea how to handle is is to keep the data only for the last second. I would use a built-in data-structure like a LinkedList to store the data (O(1) for insertion).

Whenever the dashboard is updated (so a GET comes in), I make a copy of the LinkedList and create a new empty LinkedList that will be updated with the new incoming data. I will use the copy to compute sum and average and return it to the display.

Am I missing something here? Is there a faster, less memory-consuming way to do this?